# call class method on onclick of apex:tab visualforce page

Tags: tabs, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, tabpanel

I have developed a visualforce page where I have used apex:tab and apex:commandButton. apex:commandButton is in under apex:tab. Now, I am using commandButton for check validation and calling class method. But I want to do same thing on tab click also. I have used switchType="ajax", it is working and tab is changing but I can't find out how can I call a class method on tab click.
I am using below code:-

```
    <apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:actionStatus id="tabStatus" startText="Processing..." onstop=""/>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="ajax" reRender="formId" value="{!currentTab}" id="theTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" activeTabClass="activeTab" contentStyle="font-size: 12px;">
        <apex:tab switchType="ajax" label="Tab1" status="tabStatus" name="Tab1" id="Tab1Id" reRender="formId">
</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab switchType="ajax" label="Tab2" status="tabStatus" name="Tab2" id="Tab2Id" reRender="formId">
</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab switchType="ajax" label="Tab3" status="tabStatus" name="Tab3" id="Tab3Id" reRender="formId">
</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

can anybody help me please

> How to call a class method on click on tab?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```salesforce
<apex:actionFunction name="callClass" action="{!yourMethodName}" rerender="none" />

<apex:tab onclick="callClass()">
```

Comment: Hi @mast0r, thanks for reply. but I am getting problem in this. If I used "onclick" event then that is not effective i want "ontableave" event. so i have used below code:-
<apex:tab switchType="ajax" label="Tab1" status="tabStatus" name="Tab1" id="Tab1Id" reRender="formId" ontableave="callNext();">
<apex:actionFunction name="callNext" action="{!next}" rerender="theTabPanel" />
</apex:tab>
and i have some required fields on tab1. it checking validation but also switching to tab2. i want when any error is occurred then dont switch to another tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use selectedTab attribute in "tabPanel" to control from controler the  selectedTab
 something like

`<apex:actionFunction name="callClass" action="{!callClass}" rerender="tabPanel" />`
 `<apex:tabPanel selectedTab="{!selectedTab}" onclick="callClass()">`